# Are these spider eggs?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology, eggs

I was pulling weeds in my backyard in Southern California, when I saw a spider over a white area on the underside of one of the leaves. It's staying right near the white spot. Are those spider eggs? Also, what kind of spider is this?

[image: Spider over white spot under leaf]
[image: Spider over white spot under leaf]
[image: Spider over white spot under leaf]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, those are definitely eggs.  And I believe that is a female grass spider (Genus: *[Agelenopsis](http://www.spiders.us/species/agelenopsis-spp/)*).

> Eggs are typically laid in late summer or fall and spiderlings emerge
> the following spring....A female that has mated with a male can produce more
> than one egg sac. For some species,  it’s common to see two sacs at a
> time, side by side, attached to a surface (such as the underside of a
> rock, piece of wood in a wood pile, or in a rolled up leaf, for
> example). Each different species of Agelenopsis may create a slightly
> different egg sac, but typically each one contains anywhere from 50 to
> 200 individual eggs. The mother spider will remain near her eggs,
> dutifully guarding them, until she dies around the onset of winter.

This seems to fit the picture to a T.  I'm not 100% about the species, but I believe it is either *A. aperta* or *A. oregonensis*.

## Edit:

As user Xan pointed out, this could likely be a lynx spider (Genus: *Oxyopes*; likely species: [*Oxyopes salticus*](http://bugguide.net/node/view/545509) - female).  This would explain the defined setae (bristles) on the legs.  To really decide, you would need to check the following characteristics:

- Eye pattern: Lynx spider eyes form an octoganal pattern, while grass spider eyes form two, parallel, curved rows.
- Spinnerets: You would have to search for spinnerets on a lynx spider, while grass spiders have two very prominent hind spinnerets that you can visibly see from above.

I originally thought those were spinnerets in picture 3, but upon closer inspection it looks like one of the hind legs folded underneath.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be about right. But the pattern on the spider doesn't quite match those species.

Comment: Can't say the species, but it seems to be a lynx spider (genus [_Oxyopes_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyopes))